expected value of the Euclidean norm for a multivariate non-zero mean normal vector calculation
I found this general expresson. Could anyone assess it's correctness ?
The expected value of the Euclidean norm for a multivariate normal vector $$(\mathbf{K} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{u}, \Sigma))$$ is given by:
$$[ \mathbb{E}[\|\mathbf{K}\|] = \sqrt{2} \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)} \sqrt{\text{trace}(\Sigma) + \|\mathbf{u}\|^2} ]$$
Summary how to find:

Standardise the vector to get a standard normal distribution.
Use the chi distribution properties to find the expected value of the norm.
Relate back to the original vector using the variance (trace of $(\Sigma)$ and the mean $((\mathbf{u}))$.
Combine these results using the properties of the Gamma function to obtain the final expectation.

This approach uses the relationship between the multivariate normal distribution and the chi distribution to derive the expected value of the Euclidean norm.

Have you checked if it works in case $n=1$?

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144893/what-is-the-expected-norm-mathbb-e-lvert-x-rvert-for-a-multivariate-normal?newreg=a82409c8a0954e7caf9a897d04252d45
